# IE Positioning Help

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, xhtml

I’m currently working on this theme : http://tf.ffffffive.com/fancy/

I just need a few pointers on how to get it working in IE6 and IE7 .

-The positioning is a bit off. 
-If you guys have a helpful blog post of maybe give me a hand with some CSS coding I would really appreciate it.

Also the Javascript scrolling effect isn't working correctly due to the positioning. Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks, Henry

Answer (score 0):

It might help not to use the mozilla specific tags of -moz-*. Another suggestion is to be wary of PNGs with IE6. It doesn't always do with them what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries around the web to cover IE positioning and alike bugs. If they solve the problem for you, it's better than having to have separate stylesheets for IE and loading them selectively with [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx).

I'd recommend that you give a look, for instance, at the [IE7-JS](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) library.

Answer (score 0):

Most of cross-browser CSS bugs come from using 'complicated' style patterns.  Absolute positioning is one of these 'complicated' style patterns.  If you get rid of absolute positioning and use other methods of element positioning (margins, padding, floats) its likely that your page will render better in IE6/IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSS hacks , there is one jQuery Browser detection solution, you can detect the browser and add specific and valid CSS.

like for ie6

```
.ie6 .classname 
.ie7 .classname
```

http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/